# Switch statement executing 2 things instead of just 1

Tags: java, android, firebase, switch-statement, toolbar

Sorry for the vague title, I just don't know how to describe this diffrently.

My problem is with a switch statement, which is used to handle the click events of an menuitem in my toolbar.

The toolbar consists of 2 menuItems, a Favorite button (whichs is showen) and a Unfavorite button (which is not visible). When clicked on the favorite button, the item gets added to the favorites and the button gets hidden. The the unfavorite button will be made visible.

The problem:
- The first part, adding the item to the favorites and showing the unfavorite button works fine.
- The second part does the following: When clicked on the Unfavorite button the item will be deleted from the favorites, be also added again to the database straight away. I can't seem te find out why sadly. It looks like the exact code from the adding to favorites button is executed here asswell.

Maby it's just a small mistake, but I haven't been able to see it. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
When changing the return true of the UnFavoriteBtn case to a break, the will delete the values properly, only then there is no toast showen that the data is deleted and the menuItem does not change back to the favorite button.
When changing both the cases return true to break, the app will crash when clicked on the menu item.

The code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.FavoriteBtn:

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String key = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");

                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    UserID = user.getUid();

                    String dienstverband = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Dienstverband").getValue(String.class);
                    String functie = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Functie").getValue(String.class);
                    String functie_locatie = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Functie_Locatie").getValue(String.class);
                    String locatie = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Locatie").getValue(String.class);
                    String omschrijving = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Omschrijving").getValue(String.class);
                    String omschrijving_volledig = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Omschrijving volledig").getValue(String.class);
                    String opleidingsniveau = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Opleidingsniveau").getValue(String.class);
                    String salarisschaal = dataSnapshot.child("Vacatures").child(key).child("Salarisschaal").getValue(String.class);

                    HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    dataMap.put("Functie", functie);
                    dataMap.put("Key", key);
                    dataMap.put("Locatie", locatie);
                    dataMap.put("Omschrijving", omschrijving);
                    dataMap.put("Omschrijving volledig", omschrijving_volledig);
                    dataMap.put("Opleidingsniveau", opleidingsniveau);
                    dataMap.put("Dienstverband", dienstverband);
                    dataMap.put("Salarisschaal", salarisschaal);
                    dataMap.put("Functie_Locatie", functie_locatie);

                    myRef.child("Favorites").child(UserID).child(key).setValue(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vacature aan favorieten toegevoegd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mMenu.findItem(R.id.FavoriteBtn).setVisible(false);
                            mMenu.findItem(R.id.UnFavoriteBtn).setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
            return true;

        case R.id.UnFavoriteBtn:

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef2 = mDatabase.getReference();

            String key = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            UserID = user.getUid();

            myRef2.child("Favorites").child(UserID).child(key).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vacature uit favorieten verwijderd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mMenu.findItem(R.id.FavoriteBtn).setVisible(true);
                    mMenu.findItem(R.id.UnFavoriteBtn).setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            return true;
    }
    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The toolbar menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/FavoriteBtn"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border"
    android:title="Favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/UnFavoriteBtn"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
    android:title="UnFavorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

Comment: How are you handling visibility of menu items? Share the code.

Answer (score 0):

addvalueListener is to listen (means if there is any change on database change it will trigger).

that's why that paricular block execute twice.
First when you click on menu item (it insert data to firebase)
Second because firebase got change in database so that is trigger.

SO put your insertion code outside of eventListener block.

```
 HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    dataMap.put("Functie", functie);
                    dataMap.put("Key", key);
                    dataMap.put("Locatie", locatie);
                    dataMap.put("Omschrijving", omschrijving);
                    dataMap.put("Omschrijving volledig", omschrijving_volledig);
                    dataMap.put("Opleidingsniveau", opleidingsniveau);
                    dataMap.put("Dienstverband", dienstverband);
                    dataMap.put("Salarisschaal", salarisschaal);
                    dataMap.put("Functie_Locatie", functie_locatie);

                    myRef.child("Favorites").child(UserID).child(key).setValue(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vacature aan favorieten toegevoegd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mMenu.findItem(R.id.FavoriteBtn).setVisible(false);
                            mMenu.findItem(R.id.UnFavoriteBtn).setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
```

Only put this code in switch block to insert your data.

Answer (score 0):

"only then there is no toast showen that the data is deleted and the menuItem does not change back to the favorite button" is the OnSuccess callback method is actually being called ? do a log inside addOnSuccessListener before onSuccess see if it actually being called or not...if yes do a log inside onSucess and check